# Informix Database - Create table with a datetime column, getting DEFAULT value syntax errors

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

Attempting to create a table with a default DATETIME. My code looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    start_time DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 09:00:00.000'
    end_time DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 17:00:00.000
    daily_max INT NOT NULL
    ...some other columns...
)
```

When I attempt to execute this, I get this error and it fails to create the table..

> [Error Code: -591, SQL State: IX000]  Invalid default value for column/variable (start_time).

Is there a specific DATETIME format I need to use when declaring the column's default value? I've looked at [IBM's Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_110.htm) for this and believe I am using the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the default using the long-winded DATETIME literal format:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    start_time DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION NOT NULL DEFAULT
               DATETIME(0001-01-01 09:00:00.000) YEAR TO FRACTION,
    end_time   DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION NOT NULL DEFAULT
               DATETIME(0001-01-01 17:00:00.000) YEAR TO FRACTION,
    daily_max  INT NOT NULL,
    …some other columns…
)
```

I went for uniformity (and simplicity) using plain `FRACTION` consistently, which means the same as `FRACTION(3)`.  Most people weren't in 9-5 jobs back at the beginning of time AD (Anno Domini) or CE (Christian Era).

See [DATETIME Literal](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1600.htm) for the details of the literal format.

Comment: Thank you! This syntax did the trick. I tried a various number of ways, almost exactly like the answer here, but resources for Informix SQL syntax are (understandably) limited...